# Mapping multiple arrays in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, iteration, jsx

I'm trying to display some html elements in a certain way when mapping over the arrays in JSX. I want it to be like:

*Title 

Link*

*Title 

Link*

But when I try, I always end up with it displayed like this:

Title 
Title

Link 
Link

This is how the array is structured.

[image]

In my code this is how I'm mapping over the arrays.

```
{audioInfo.map((item, index) => {
                   
   return ( <div key={index}>

                        
     <div>{item.filename[0].name}</div>
                            
         {

          item.url.map((u,i)=>(
              <div key={i}>
                                
                 <audio controls src={u}> </audio>
              </div>
           ))
         }
  </div> )
 })}
```

This is the part I'm having trouble with.

```
item.filename[0].name
```

This only gets the first filename but I'm not sure how I would be able to iterate to the next filename while still rendering the html like I want. It should be in pairs with the `filename` and `url` in each map iteration. I hope that makes sense.

Full Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import storage from "firebase/storage";
import  firebaseConfig from "../dropzone/config";

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link,
    useRouteMatch,
    BrowserRouter,
    useParams
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { isElement } from 'react-dom/test-utils';


if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

}else {
    firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}

  // router is getting the current path name


const FolderPage = () => {

    let {folder} = useParams();

    let fb_storage = firebase.storage();
    let storageRef = fb_storage.ref();  
    
    let rootRef = storageRef.child(folder);


    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]); 
   
    const [audioInfo, setAudioInfo] = useState([]);    

        
    const fileNames =  () =>{
        let temp = [];
        rootRef.listAll().then( function(res) {
            
            let promises = res.items.map(item => item.getDownloadURL());

            Promise.all(promises).then((downloadURLs)=>{
                        
                  
                    setAudioInfo([
                        {
                            filename:res.items, 
                            url: downloadURLs 
                        }  
                    ])
                })
          
            }).catch(function(error) {
           
        });
            
    
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        fileNames();
    },[])


    console.log(audioInfo)
    

    return (
        <>
            <div>hello {folder}</div>
          

            <div>

                
                {audioInfo.map((item, index) => {
                   
                   return ( <div key={index}>

       
                           <div>{item.filename[0].name}</div>
                            
                            {

                            item.url.map((u,i)=>(
                               <div key={i}>
                                <span>{u.name}</span>   
                                <audio controls src={u}> </audio>
                               </div>
                            ))
                            }

                           
                    </div> )
                    })}
                
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default FolderPage
```

Comment: `res.items` is a bunch of unresolved promises. Why are you setting filename to `res.items`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this you can create a variable before setting audioInfo state.

```
const files = []
res.items.map((item, i)=>{
  files.push({url: downloadURLs[i], file: item.name })     
})
setAudioInfo(files)
```

Now you can simply iterate and render

```
<div>                
     {audioInfo.map((item, index) => {                   
       return ( <div key={index}>                           
        <span>{item.file}</span>   
        <audio controls src={item.url}> </audio>                                                        
        </div> )
       })}                
</div>
```

Comment: what a legend! worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting two maps, just set them into states then use one of those states to loop over, this assumes that each filename has a single url at the same index assosiated with it.

```
const [names, setNames] = useState([])
const [urls, setURL] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    audioInfo[0].filename.forEach((i) => setNames([...names, i.name]))
    audioInfo[0].url.forEach((i) => setURL([...urls, i]))
}, [])

{
    names.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <div>{item}</div>
                <div key={index}>
                    <audio controls src={urls[index]} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`res.items` is an array of [References](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) returned by your `rootRef.listAll()` and when you set is as the `filename` you can't magically pull the `name` property like this `{item.filename[0].name}`

Consider refactoring your `fileNames` function to resolve to an array of objects where the `filename` key is set to the `name` of each `item`.

```js
const fileNames = () => {
  let temp = [];
  rootRef
    .listAll()
    .then(function (res) {

      let promises = res.items.map((item) =>
        item.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURLs) =>
          Promise.resolve([
            {
              filename: item.name,
              url: downloadURLs,
            },
          ]));
      );

      Promise.all(promises).then((audioInfo) => {
        setAudioInfo(audioInfo);
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {});
};
```

Now within your JSX, you can reference `filename` by simply

```
<div>{item.filename}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing index directly you can use map index.
Here I have declared dummy json list based on your json and render output like you asked

```
export default function App() {
  const list = [
    {
      file: ["ABC", "CDE"],
      url: ["link1", "link2"]
    },
    {
      file: ["ABC2", "CDE2"],
      url: ["link12", "link22"]
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>List Map</h1>
      {list.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            {item.file.map((file, pos) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <p>file : {file}</p>
                  <p>Url : {item.url[pos]}</p>
                  <hr/>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]